# Spring boot Jaxb Exception

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jaxb, entitymanager

I am biulding a spring boot application. but not getting the desired output. Can anyone help for this basic application.

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path
>   resource
>   [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]:
>   Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

Topic.java

```
    package com.example.demo.topics;
    import javax.persistence.Entity;
    import javax.persistence.Id;

    @Entity
    public class Topic {


    @Id
    String topicId;
    String topicName;
    String topicDescription;

    public Topic()  {}

    public Topic(String topicId, String topicName, String topicDescription) {
        super();
        this.topicId = topicId;
        this.topicName = topicName;
        this.topicDescription = topicDescription;
    }
    public String getTopicId() {
        return topicId;
    }
    public void setTopicId(String topicId) {
        this.topicId = topicId;
    }
    public String getTopicName() {
        return topicName;
    }
    public void setTopicName(String topicName) {
        this.topicName = topicName;
    }
    public String getTopicDescription() {
        return topicDescription;
    }
    public void setTopicDescription(String topicDescription) {
        this.topicDescription = topicDescription;
    }   
}
```

Controller class

```
package com.example.demo.topics;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class TopicController {

    @Autowired
    TopicService topicService;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    private String getWelcome() {
        return "Hello";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/topics")
    private List<Topic> getTopics() {
        return topicService.getTopics();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/topics/{id}")
    private Topic getTopicById(String id) {
        return topicService.getTopicbyId(id);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/topics/{id}")
    private void putTopic(Topic topic) {
         topicService.putTopic(topic);
    }

}
```

Repository Class

```
package com.example.demo.topics;

import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface TopicRepository extends CrudRepository<Topic,String>{

}
```

Service class

```
package com.example.demo.topics;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class TopicService {

    @Autowired
    private TopicRepository topicRepository;



    public List<Topic> getTopics() {
        List<Topic> topics= new ArrayList<Topic>();
         topicRepository.findAll().forEach(topics::add);

         return topics;
    }

    public Topic getTopicbyId(String id) {
        return topicRepository.findOne(id);
    }

    public void putTopic(Topic topic) {
         topicRepository.save(topic);
    }





}
```

pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>springboottopics</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>springboottopics</name>
<description>First Java Brains project for Spring Boot</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.9</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.derby</groupId>
        <artifactId>derby</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image]

console:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.9.RELEASE)

2017-12-29 20:29:50.365  INFO 2941 --- [           main] c.e.demo.SpringboottopicsApplication     : Starting SpringboottopicsApplication on Abhays-MacBook-Air.local with PID 2941 (/Users/abhaysingh/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE/springboottopics/target/classes started by abhaysingh in /Users/abhaysingh/Documents/workspace-sts-3.9.2.RELEASE/springboottopics)
2017-12-29 20:29:50.373  INFO 2941 --- [           main] c.e.demo.SpringboottopicsApplication     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-12-29 20:29:50.481  INFO 2941 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@17503f6b: startup date [Fri Dec 29 20:29:50 IST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1 (file:/Users/abhaysingh/.m2/repository/org/springframework/spring-core/4.3.13.RELEASE/spring-core-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(java.lang.String,byte[],int,int,java.security.ProtectionDomain)
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.springframework.cglib.core.ReflectUtils$1
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
2017-12-29 20:29:53.356  INFO 2941 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-12-29 20:29:53.402  INFO 2941 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2017-12-29 20:29:53.405  INFO 2941 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.23
2017-12-29 20:29:53.690  INFO 2941 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2017-12-29 20:29:53.691  INFO 2941 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3231 ms
2017-12-29 20:29:54.249  INFO 2941 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.ServletRegistrationBean  : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2017-12-29 20:29:54.275  INFO 2941 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-29 20:29:54.276  INFO 2941 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-29 20:29:54.277  INFO 2941 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-29 20:29:54.278  INFO 2941 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.s.b.w.servlet.FilterRegistrationBean   : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2017-12-29 20:29:57.297  INFO 2941 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2017-12-29 20:29:57.352  INFO 2941 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2017-12-29 20:29:57.627  INFO 2941 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {5.0.12.Final}
2017-12-29 20:29:57.634  INFO 2941 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2017-12-29 20:29:57.640  INFO 2941 --- [           main] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2017-12-29 20:29:57.686  WARN 2941 --- [           main] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
2017-12-29 20:29:57.696  INFO 2941 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2017-12-29 20:29:57.760  INFO 2941 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-12-29 20:29:57.807 ERROR 2941 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) ~[spring-context-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.SpringboottopicsApplication.main(SpringboottopicsApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/xml/bind/JAXBException
    at org.hibernate.boot.spi.XmlMappingBinderAccess.<init>(XmlMappingBinderAccess.java:43) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.MetadataSources.<init>(MetadataSources.java:87) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:179) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:54) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336) ~[spring-orm-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496) ~[na:na]
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

Comment: With java 9 you need to add jaxb as additional dependency.

Comment: Related : [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43574426/how-to-resolve-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-javax-xml-bind-jaxbexception-in-j)

Answer (score 0):

Did you registered the spring.datasource , hibernate dialects in application.properties? Just for doubt

Like

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root

spring.datasource.driverClassName=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = none
```

You are missing the hibernate-core dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.11.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Still the same. Tried it,